# How can I display a graphical (ascii text graphics) representation of the decision tree in WEKA using graph() or tograph()

Tags: java, graph, weka

I'm trying to display the decision tree generated by different classes using the WEKA classes in my own program.  Specifically I'm using two different ones: J48 (C4.5 implementation) and RandomTree.  One has the function graph() and the other has the function toGraph() which appear to have the same functionality for their respective classes.

Since they both show java.lang.String as their return type I was expecting to see something like what you see when using their Explorer app:

```
act = STRETCH
|   size = SMALL
|   |   Color = YELLOW
|   |   |   age = ADULT : T (1/0)
|   |   |   age = CHILD : F (1/0)
|   |   Color = PURPLE
|   |   |   age = ADULT : T (2/0)
|   |   |   age = CHILD : F (1/0)
|   size = LARGE
|   |   age = ADULT : T (4/0)
|   |   age = CHILD : F (2/0)
act = DIP : F (8/0)
```

Instead I get something like this:

```
digraph Tree {
edge [style=bold]
N13aaa14a [label="1: T"]
N13aaa14a->N268b819f [label="act = STRETCH"]
N268b819f [label="2: T"shape=box]
N13aaa14a->N10eb017e [label="act = DIP"]
N10eb017e [label="3: F"]
N10eb017e->N34aeffdf [label="age = CHILD"]
N34aeffdf [label="4: F"shape=box]
N10eb017e->N4d20a47e [label="age = ADULT"]
N4d20a47e [label="5: T"shape=box]
}
```

Is this something unique to the WEKA libraries or is this some type of standard Java format?  It looks similar to some of the JSON stuff I saw working on another project but I never got that familiar with it.

Is there an easy way I can write a function to display this in a more human-readable format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you are getting is in so-called "dot" format which is designed to be compiled by graphviz. You'll get better results than ASCII art, that's for sure.

Save your file in `out.dot` and then try this command:

```
$ dot -Tpng -oout.png out.dot
```

Then look at what you've got in out.png